# Java files are not being pushed to github

Tags: github, android-studio

Android studio is not pushing java files to github. I found that it only pushed the src folder with the res (layouts and xml docs) folder. I tried adding the java folder to it (right click, add, then commit directory, and push), but it still does not push the java files to git.

Used this setup:
https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/

.gitignore:

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
```

When I right click on the Main folder (which holds the java files) and select commit directory, I get the following error:

```
Error:On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
 during executing git commit --only -F C:\Users\mmm\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-999645.txt -- MainActivity.java
```

Comment: Did you check `.gitignore` file?

Comment: did you try cli or not

Comment: In the gitignore, it does not seem to be ignoring any of the java files:
`.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build`

Answer (score 2):

Did it through gitbash following the instructions here:
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-from-the-command-line/

Right clicked on the main folder (containing the java files) and selected gitbash.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently. If your .gitignore looks good, you may want to check Git (local git repository) first and see if the .java files show up there.

The folder (/apps/src/main/java/myproject/bleh) where .java files were stored was flagged as "* Git Repository (subproject)" by Git and that was a consequence of a hidden .git file stored there.

Fixed it by deleting that .git file and adding the files to the repository.

Comment: because of this comment i deleted my .git file and now i am in worst condition. -1 to this comment.